PostgreSQL COPY command from csv file problem for array data
I'm working on migrating data from MongoDB to PostgreSQL. I'm using the mongoexport command to export collections into a CSV file, and then I attempt to import the data from the CSV file into a PostgreSQL table using the COPY command.
By default, array fields in the CSV file are formatted as "[""val1"",""val2""]". When I try to execute the COPY command with this CSV file, I'm getting the following error:
ERROR:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.malformed array literal: "["TRT100925T18"]" 

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["TRT100925T18"]"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
Context: COPY sgmk_hazine_tanim, line 2, column isins: "["TRT100925T18"]"

To resolve this, I manually correct the array format in Notepad++ to {val1,val2}. However, when I run the COPY command again, I receive another error because the commas within the array are interpreted as new fields:
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY sgmk_hazine_tanim, line 5: "2024-09-24T05:50:00.114Z,2025-03-11T21:00:00.000Z,121,{TRT120325T12,TRT120325T20},121T2,85.640,4" 

SQL state: 22P04

Here is my table structure:
CREATE TABLE sgmk_hazine_tanim (                   
    id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    last_update timestamp NOT NULL,
    matDate date NOT NULL,
    section smallint NOT NULL,
    isins text[] NOT NULL,
    CBRTCode VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    presVal VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    payRate NUMERIC(8,4)
);

The sgmk_hazine_tanim.csv file for the first couple of rows looks like this:
last_update,matDate,section,isins,CBRTCode,presVal,payRate
2024-09-24T05:50:00.114Z,2025-09-09T21:00:00.000Z,111,{TRT100925T18},13T,69.782,
2024-09-24T05:50:00.114Z,2024-10-15T21:00:00.000Z,111,{TRT161024T10},15T,97.120,
2024-09-24T05:50:00.114Z,2025-04-08T21:00:00.000Z,111,{TRT090425T16},15T,80.060,
2024-09-24T05:50:00.114Z,2025-03-11T21:00:00.000Z,121,{TRT120325T12,TRT120325T20},121T2,85.640,4

And here is my COPY command:
COPY sgmk_hazine_tanim(last_update,matDate,section,isins,CBRTCode,presVal,payRate) FROM '/home/srvadmin/docker/build/aktarimlar/sgmk_hazine_tanim.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

This is the mongoexport command I used:
mongoexport --uri=$URI --authenticationDatabase=$AUTH_DB --db=$DB_NAME --collection=$COLLECTION_NAME --type=csv --fields=$FIELDS --out=$OUTPUT_FILE

I considered changing the CSV delimiter from a comma to a pipe (|) and also from copy command, which might help fix the problem, but I would prefer not to deal with that. If you have any knowledge or suggestions on how to handle this issue i  would greatly appreciate.

When you do the manual correction of "[""val1"",""val2""]" to {val1,val2}, make sure that you include the outer quotes: "{val1,val2}". Otherwise, the inner comma is treated as a field separator. And I would recommend first only changing the brackets [] to braces {} and leaving the quoted items as is. So "{""val1"",""val2""}"

Yes, the issue was caused by this. I should have kept the inner commas intact thanks for pointing that out

I solved the issue with changing the format from "[""val1"",""val2""]" to "{""val1"","val2""}" with notepad++, the copy command imported it without any problems

You can accept your own answer after 48 hours.
